# How Next.js useRouter() handle the mapping variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
 const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      {Usercategory.map((user,index)=>{
        return <div className='user-li' key={index} onClick={()=>{router.push(user.link)}}>
                <li> 
                  {user.icon}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span>{user.name}</span>
                  <span>{user.entry}</span>
                </li>
               </div>
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

On above ,

onClick={()=>{router.push(user.link)}

Couldn't work ?

How can I finish this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `div`  element with a `Link`, like so:

```
{Usercategory.map((user,index)=>{
        return <Link href={user.link} key={index}><div className='user-li'  >
                <li> 
                  {user.icon}
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span>{user.name}</span>
                  <span>{user.entry}</span>
                </li>
               </div>
          </Link>
      })}
```

Also, separate from your question, using index as key is wrong.  It would be better if you use `user.link` or `user.name` as your key, because react/next automatically uses index as a key if you don't declare a key.

Comment: Thanks ,I know use Index as a key will cause mistake when the mapping object missing properties, and it's impossible to use onclick navigator on map in nextjs right?

Comment: The React key goes on the ***outer-most*** mapped element, the `Link` in this case. Leaving it on the `div` element won't do much. I suggest also showing what/where this `Link` component comes from.

Comment: oh, sorry, it slipped out, I will update my answer. thanks!